# How can I publish many dependant subprojects in a certain order with gradle?

Tags: gradle, dependency-management, maven-publish

I'm trying to publish two subprojects with gradle. I have two subprojects: SubprojectA is dependant on SubprojectB. I want to publish them both using maven-publish. I have this in build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'maven-publish'
}

publishing {
    publications {
        SubprojectA(MavenPublication) {
            println(project(':subprojectA').tasks)
            groupId group
            artifactId 'subjprojectA'
            version version
            artifact project(':subprojectA').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
        SubprojectB(MavenPublication) {
                groupId group
                artifactId 'subjprojectB'
                version version
                artifact project(':subjprojectB').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
                url "http://some-url"
        }
    }
}
```

Gradle tries to publish them in alphabetical order: Since subprojectA depends on subprojectB, it doesn't work because subprojectB hasn't been published yet. If I rename subprojectA to ZSubprojectA, like this:

```
        ZSubprojectA(MavenPublication) {
            println(project(':subprojectA').tasks)
            groupId group
            artifactId 'subprojectA'
            version version
            artifact project(':subprojectA').tasks.getByName('jar')
        }
```

then it works, but I don't like this solution. I've tried something like this:

```
project(':subprojectA') {
    publish.dependsOn(":subprojectB:build")
}
```

but it doesn't work, and :subprojectB:publish doesn't exist.

Comment: *it doesn't work because subprojectB hasn't been published yet*: why does that matter? What is the error you're getting?

Comment: Because subprojectA needs subprojectB. If it isn't in my maven repository, then it can't be found. It will print something like: Could not find com.myorg.something.subprojectB. Searched in the following locations.... (it can't be found in any location because it wasn't published yet). Required by: project :subprojectA

Comment: Could you please post the exact and complete message and stack trace of the error in your question?

Comment: I've been able to solve it. You can see my answer if you want. Thanks for your help- just as you said, the order of the publications shouldn't matter if you add dependencies correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've been able to solve it. This was the problem:

Both subprojects had their respective build.gradle files. In subprojectA's build.gradle there was something like this:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
    implementation group: 'com.neovisionaries', name: 'nv-i18n', version: '1.22'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.1'
    implementation group: 'com.myorg.something', name: 'subprojectB', version: '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

}
```

Therefore it was trying to get subprojectB from my organization private repository, and I should have done something like this:

```
compile project(":subprojectB")
```

I should have include both build.gradle files in my question. But the problem is solved.